# Does nodejs use less resources than Play framework?

Tags: java, node.js, playframework

Are there any benchmarks other than http://www.subbu.org/blog/2011/03/nodejs-vs-play-for-front-end-apps

that compares how much resources nodejs uses compared to play framework?

Comment: "resources" is a useless and generic term. What's the real problem your trying to solve. What are the properties of the problem which you believe node or play might be more suitable to

Comment: basically trying to see which is suitable for using less memory on a linux vps with very 512mb for serving a blog

Comment: I run a node.js blog and it takes about 120mb un optimised.

Comment: and how much compared to wordpress on apache?

Comment: apache consumes memory like a beast, but that's because it's apache

Comment: that is good to know. what blog are you using for nodejs?

Comment: Hand written, raynos.org

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A direct comparison in this case is almost impossible. Because that is completely different instruments based on different technologies. For example a non-blocking IO in node.js and blocking in the Play Framework. But it is possible to implement non-blocking IO in the Play Framework. Results may vary. They will always be vary because the tools are always evolving. Compare something like 'Hello world' is useless. These tests do not show real results. Which tool to choose depends only on a particular task. Application performance depends only on the developer skill.